# Generic overloaded method with nullable param call concrete type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, overloading, nullable

I want to be able to call the generic foo method which has a Nullable param.  When the body of the Foo method calls the Foo(), it goes recursive, resulting in a stack overflow (without the .com).  Is there a way to have the call in the if statement call the correct overload with the runtime type?

I know changing the names would do it and I understand why the recursion is happening, but don't know of another way to write this.

Thanks for looking.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int? x = 5;
        int y = 10;
        Foo(x, y);
    }

    static void Foo<T>(Nullable<T> arg, T defaultValue) where T : struct {
        if (arg.HasValue)
            Foo(arg.Value, defaultValue);
    }

    static void Foo(int arg, int defaultValue) {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("I'm an int arg={0}, default={1]}", arg, defaultValue));
    }

    static void Foo(string arg, int defaultValue) {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("I'm an string arg={0}, default={1]}", arg, defaultValue));
    }

    static void Foo(bool arg, int defaultValue) {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("I'm an double arg={0}, default={1]}", arg, defaultValue));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would you expect `double?` to go?

Comment: Try explicit casting the arguments in the call the Foo()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics are a compile time feature, overload resolution has been decided before the program ever runs. If you want to, as you say, force a runtime decision, you could employ `dynamic` to achieve that goal (in C# 4+). Short of that, you simply must cast to the applicable type between int and bool otherwise.

```
  if (arg.HasValue) 
        Foo((dynamic)arg.Value, defaultValue);
```

But beware! This only solves your problem for `int` and `bool`. Other types could be passed to the generic method, and those will continue to resolve to the generic method on the subsequent call.

```
 Foo(5.0, 10.0); // would still overflow with your given methods
```

Follow your initial judgment, if you want to support `int`, `string`, and `bool`, simply have those overloads. If you want to support any given T, create an overload for T.

```
static void Foo<T>(T arg, T defaultValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("I'm a T arg={0}, default={1}", arg, defaultValue));
}
```

Overload resolution will still pick `int`, `bool`, `string`, or `T?` overloads if they are applicable *based upon compile time information*. All other calls, *and* the call with `arg.Value`, will go to this new overload.

Comment: thank you Anthony, dynamic did what I would like.  As the sample I provided is not my real code, there is a limited number of types which could be passed.  I like your idea of changing all methods to one generic method.  I'm going to look to see if my overloads can support that.  The non-generic methods is legacy code, so I wanted to limit the amount of new code introduced.